# Java Compiler on Mac

Tags: java, macos, terminal

I have a windows .bat compiler that I'd like to run on my Mac using terminal.

So my question is, how do I convert the .bat code to work in terminal on mac?

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin\javac.exe" -classpath deps/log4j-1.2.15.jar;deps/jython.jar;deps/xstream.jar;deps/mina.jar;deps/mysql.jar;deps/RuneTopListV2.jar;deps/poi.jar;deps/slf4j.jar;deps/slf4j-nop.jar -d bin src\core\*.java src\core\net\*.java src\core\task\*.java src\core\util\*.java src\core\util\log\*.java src\server\*.java src\server\clip\*.java src\server\clip\region\*.java src\server\content\*.java src\server\content\quests\*.java src\server\content\quests\misc\*.java src\server\content\skills\*.java src\server\content\skills\misc\*.java src\server\event\*.java src\server\game\items\*.java src\server\game\minigames\barrows\*.java src\server\game\minigames\castlewars\*.java src\server\game\minigames\pestcontrol\*.java src\server\game\minigames\tzhaar\*.java src\server\game\npcs\*.java src\server\game\objects\*.java src\server\game\objects\doors\*.java src\server\game\players\*.java src\server\game\players\combat\*.java src\server\game\players\packets\*.java src\server\game\shops\*.java src\server\world\*.java src\server\world\map\*.java
pause
```

Comment: By rewriting it to a shell script.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/OpenSource/Conceptual/ShellScripting/shell_scripts/shell_scripts.html in addition to @elliottFrish comment

Comment: By all means learn how to use a contemporary build tool like Maven or Gradle!